Yellow fruit with calyx, long leaves
What species of plant is this?

Location: Greece
Date: April 30, 2024
Description: Yellow fruit with calyx, long leaves



This is the Loquat (Eriobotrya japonica). Loqat, as the scientific name suggests are an asiatic plant propagated for their edible fruit. They are a large shrub to small tree form and have long, tough, rough-textured, dark green leaves.
Fruit, which are 2-5 cm (~1-2 in) across, grow in clusters off a spike-like shape. There is a large brown stone/seed inside the fruit and the fruit will be yellow or orange when ripe.

Addition of a figure and confirmation of the distribution of the plant can help a lot; the pic is from Greece and your ID is an Asian one; of course it can be imported, but with the limited info available in the Q, it does add uncertainty to your ID imo

Definitely Loquat; the leaves are a giveaway.  Also, it s a hardy plant, widely domesticated, including in Greece, and if you're lucky enough to find a good breed, delicious.
